# How to remember which videos of a certain user on Vimeo I have already watched?

Tags: vimeo

There are some users on [Vimeo](http://vimeo.com) whose videos I would like to watch completely. If a user has >100 Videos, it’s not that easy to remember which ones I have seen already. 
It would be really handy to have a list of videos and after every watched one the list gets smaller.

I could «heart» every single video, but that would destroy the actual purpose of likes.
I could click every single one of them and add them to my «watch later», but that would take ages to do manually and I would like not to have to write a script for this.

Any ideas on this?

Comment: Writing a script is probably the easiest way, I'm not sure there's any other solution at the moment!

Comment: Probably there is not…